# How can I write a byte array to a file in Java?

Tags: java

How to write a byte array to a file in Java?

Comment: can you put some code and show what exactly you want to write to the file?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [IOUtils.write(byte[] data, OutputStream output)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128);
SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("target-file"));
IOUtils.write(encoded, output);
```

Comment: Why add a 3rd party library for this?

Comment: The OP does not ask AES encoding of the byteArray.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal Not in her/his original question (which they should have updated!), but see the first and third comment here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769776/how-can-i-write-a-byte-array-to-a-file-in-java#comments-1769788

Comment: @lutz is doing PR for Apache Commons.

Comment: +1 for FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("target-file"));

Answer (score 74):

As [Sebastian Redl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684370/157672) points out the most straight forward now [java.nio.file.Files.write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-). Details for this can be found in the [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

---

Old answer:
[FileOutputStream.write(byte[])](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte[]%29)  would be the most straight forward. What is the data you want to write?

The [tutorials for Java IO system](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) may be of some use to you.

Comment: byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();

i need to write encoded to a text file

Comment: KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128);
SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();

Comment: Then simply use FileOutputStream.

Comment: +1 for mentioning tutorials... (you'd received even a +2 if you mentioned www.google.com - OK, that was nasty, but it's not rovers first question...)

Comment: You should wrap the FileOutputStream in a BufferedOutputStream as suggested by @JuanZe.  Performance is much better.

Comment: Using `FileOutputStream` works under Android, while `java.nio.file` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 35):

As of Java 1.7, there's a new way: [`java.nio.file.Files.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128);
SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();
Files.write(Paths.get("target-file"), encoded);
```

Java 1.7 also resolves the embarrassment that Kevin describes: reading a file is now:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("source-file"));
```

Comment: This is probably the recommended way nowadays. All the `SecretKey` stuff is not needed; just call `Files.write()`. Thanks Sebastian!

Answer (score 16):

A commenter asked "why use a third-party library for this?" The answer is that it's way too much of a pain to do it yourself.  Here's an example of how to *properly* do the inverse operation of reading a byte array from a file (sorry, this is just the code I had readily available, and it's not like I want the asker to actually paste and use this code anyway):

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(File file) throws IOException { 
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
   boolean threw = true; 
   InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file); 
   try { 
     byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE]; 
     long total = 0; 
     while (true) { 
       int r = in.read(buf); 
       if (r == -1) {
         break; 
       }
       out.write(buf, 0, r); 
     } 
     threw = false; 
   } finally { 
     try { 
       in.close(); 
     } catch (IOException e) { 
       if (threw) { 
         log.warn("IOException thrown while closing", e); 
       } else {
         throw e;
       } 
     } 
   } 
   return out.toByteArray(); 
 }
```

Everyone ought to be thoroughly appalled by what a pain that is.

**Use Good Libraries.**  I, unsurprisingly, recommend Guava's [Files.write(byte[], File)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#write%28byte[],%20java.io.File%29).

Comment: I am appalled by what a pain that is, but also that this sort of thing isn't in the standard library.  We're not talking about an obscure file format, but moving bytes from memory to disk.

Comment: best answer: Guava's Files.write(byte[], File).

Comment: I'll take this answer over libraries! You may be interested in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074875/read-write-bytes-to-and-from-a-file-using-only-java-io

Answer (score 12):

To write a byte array to a file use the method

```
public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException
```

from BufferedOutputStream class.

[java.io.BufferedOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) implements a buffered output stream. By setting up such an output stream, an application can write bytes to the underlying output stream without necessarily causing a call to the underlying system for each byte written.

For your example you need something like:

```
String filename= "C:/SO/SOBufferedOutputStreamAnswer";
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
try {
//create an object of FileOutputStream
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));

//create an object of BufferedOutputStream
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); 
kgen.init(128); 
SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey(); 
byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();

bos.write(encoded);

} 
// catch and handle exceptions...
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning BufferedOutputStream.  You should ALWAYS wrap a FileOutputStream in a BufferedOutputStream, performance is much better.

Comment: If all you want to write to the file is a 16 byte key, wrapping the FileOutputStream in a BufferedOutputStream is probably slower than writing the data directly to the FileOutputStream.

Comment: @SamBarnum Can you elaborate? Why is wrapping the FOS in a BOS faster?

Comment: It depends on which write() method you use. If you're writing a byte at a time (or in small chunks), that results in a lot of disk activity. If your disk is network mounted, this can be catastrophic.

Comment: Well he did say "can be" catastrophic. Man, damn devs always got to be nitpicky and argumentative... :P

Answer (score 7):

[Apache Commons IO Utils](http://commons.apache.org/io/description.html) has a [FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeByteArrayToFile%28java.io.File,%20byte[]%29) method. Note that if you're doing any file/IO work then the Apache Commons IO library will do a lot of work for you.

Comment: Link is dead (Jim).

Answer (score 4):

No need for external libs to bloat things - especially when working with Android. Here is a native solution that does the trick. This is a pice of code from an app that stores a byte array as an image file.

```
    // Byte array with image data.
    final byte[] imageData = params[0];

    // Write bytes to tmp file.
    final File tmpImageFile = new File(ApplicationContext.getInstance().getCacheDir(), "scan.jpg");
    FileOutputStream tmpOutputStream = null;
    try {
        tmpOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpImageFile);
        tmpOutputStream.write(imageData);
        Log.d(TAG, "File successfully written to tmp file");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: " + e);
        return null;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e);
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        if(tmpOutputStream != null)
            try {
                tmpOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         File file = ...
         byte[] data = ...
         try{
            FileOutputStream fos = FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
         }catch(Exception e){
          }
```

but if the bytes array length is more than 1024 you should use loop to write the data.